# Cannot find value `css` in this scope [E0425]

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to build a chatbot using Rustformers LLM and some other tools. The main.rs file is strangely producing `` Cannot find value `css` in this scope [E0425] `` even when the function is defined in the right scope and is accessible. I tried moving it out of the main function but the error persists. Any suggestions?

```
use cfg_if::cfg_if;

use api::ws;
pub mod api;
pub mod model;

#[cfg(feature = "ssr")]
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    env_logger::init();

    use actix_files::Files;
    use actix_web::*;
    use leptos::*;
    use leptos_actix::{generate_route_list, LeptosRoutes};
    use rusty_llama::app::*;

    let conf = get_configuration(None).await.unwrap();
    let addr = conf.leptos_options.site_addr;

    let routes = generate_route_list(|| view! { <App/> });

    #[get("/style.css")] 
    async fn css() -> impl Responder {           // --> The function
        actix_files::NamedFile::open_async("./style/output.css").await
    }

    let model = web::Data::new(get_language_model());
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let leptos_options = &conf.leptos_options;
        let site_root = &leptos_options.site_root;

        App::new()
            .app_data(model.clone())
            .service(css)                     // --> Error in this line
            .route("/ws", web::get().to(ws))
            .route("/api/{tail:.*}", leptos_actix::handle_server_fns())
            .leptos_routes(
                leptos_options.to_owned(),
                routes.to_owned(),
                || view! { <App/> },
            )
            .service(Files::new("/", site_root))
    })
        .bind(&addr)?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Comment: Try moving the function outside of `main()`, I suspect the `#[get]` attribute doesn't work well in this scenario.

Comment: I did try moving it out of main,it's throwing the same error.

Comment: At a first glance it looks like `actix_web` generates a [type](https://docs.rs/actix-web-codegen/4.2.2/src/actix_web_codegen/route.rs.html#461) when processing the `#[get]` attribute (and others). The function itself does still exist, but it is declared within an `impl` block, so it is not declared in the original scope.